# Isolating cells with one word in them

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column filled with names. Some cells have one name, some cells have multiple names separated by a break (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>), no names are repeated.
I'm trying to figure out a function that will essentially scan the column and create, at minimum, a new list of names containing only names from the cells that have only one name in them, and possibly a second list of names containing only the names from cells that have more than one.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first column (without line break) you have to filter your data, looking for cells which do not contain line break (Ctrl+Enter is `CHAR(10)`). This means you filter with rows where the `FIND(CHAR(10),$A1:$A10)` does not return error:

```
=FILTER($A1:$A10,ISERROR(FIND(CHAR(10),$A1:$A10)))
```

The second column is more difficult: here you filter for rows that actually contain `CHAR(10)`. After this, you have to get the data in a tricky way: first, you concatenate every cell you found with the line break character, so you have one value, then you split this value on the line breaks:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(FILTER($A1:$A10,NOT(ISERROR(FIND(CHAR(10),$A1:$A10)))) & CHAR(10))), CHAR(10)))
```

This results in the format you described:

[image]

Comment: That is awesome!  Works perfect.  Sorry it took so long to respond, I honestly just forgot to reply, and noticed after realizing I had a follow-up question.  Is it possible to do the reverse?  Such as make Cell E1 contain all the names listed in the range D1:D9? Preferably with line breaks?

Comment: Yes, of course :) That would be a simple textjoin function: =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), true, D1:D9)

Comment: Appreciate the help so much!  So if I use =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), true, A4:D4) on the above sheet, I'm going to get an output of a single cell that has George, Anthony, and Mary listed with line breaks. Last question I think. Is there a way to carry formatting with it? So if say above A4 text was purple, C4 text was green, and D4 text was orange, can we make the final cell have those 3 listed with the same coloring scheme?

Comment: Sadly I don't know anything about that, but I sense that copying formats is not likely to be possible without scripting: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50409/cell-reference-with-colour-formatting